# как прочесть n количество строк ? в с++

Tags: c++, строки, getline

Вроде задача простая - просто прочитать n количество строк из консоли , но программа читает n-1 кол-во строчек

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Я думаю вся проблема в том , что после того как мы вводим значение n, мы автоматом переходим на новую строку, и после `getline()` читает пустую строчку.

Как это исправить ? Если вы очень умные , подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту задачу по другому (без `getline()`)